# Label position lagging behind Mouse Cursor C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

A label is displayed next to my mouse Cursor showing the Mouse Coordinates relative to a canvas. But when I move the mouse fast, the Label is lagging behind the Cursor. How can I keep the Label at a constant distance?

```
Label lbl = new Label
{
    Content = "HI",
    Foreground = Brushes.Black
};

private void SetLabelToMouse(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Content = Convert.ToString(SnapToGrid(e.GetPosition(picCanvas)));
        lbl.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(e.GetPosition(picCanvas).X + 10, 
        e.GetPosition(picCanvas).Y + 10);
    }
```

I also tried using this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(lbl, e.GetPosition(picCanvas).X + 10);
Canvas.SetTop(lbl, e.GetPosition(picCanvas).Y + 10);
```

Comment: That's just the positions reported to your application, which do obviously always lag a bit behind the actual cursor position on screen. You can't do much about it.

Comment: You should probably just show the label once the mouse has come to a rest and stopped for a moment.  Trying to generate/move controls constantly is only going to slow your app down.  I would use a timer and check the mouse x/y and if it's the same over the timespan of the trigger pop up the label.  WPF rendering is not really designed  for real time updates.

Comment: wpf also has its own UI redraw schedule so even if you get the coordinates in real-time, ui display will still lag behind.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I will try showing the Label when the mouse has stopped for a moment.

Comment: You may also set `Cursor="None"` on the Canvas and draw your own at the last received position. A crosshair marker for example.

Comment: Or show the coordinates at a fixed position e.g., a canvas status bar. This way you can show the values while moving the cursor.